# How to restore accidentally deleted kdesu

Tags: package-management, mageia

Trying to create a link to kdesu with:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/kdesu /usr/lib64/kde4/libexec/kdesu
```

I ended up without kdesu (I might have interchanged source and destination, not sure). Which is the package to reinstall kdesu? I can't find it. I'm using Mageia, but it should be similar in different distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mageia uses rpm for package management, so use the following command to find which package contains the file `/usr/bin/kdesu`:

```
rpm -qf /usr/bin/kdesu
```

And to reinstall the program (use the right package names, I don't have Mageia to check):

```
urpmi --replacepkgs libkdesu5 kdebase4-runtime
```

Comment: It worked with these tweaks: kdesu is located in /usr/lib64/kde4/libexec/kdesu instead of /usr/bin/kdesu and urpmi must be executed with sudo (and no need of libkdesu5). Worked great, thanks @Gilles.

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora 20 it's in this package:

```
$ repoquery -ql kde-runtime-0:4.13.3-3.fc20.x86_64 | grep kdesu
/usr/bin/kdesu
/usr/libexec/kde4/kdesu
/usr/libexec/kde4/kdesud
```

I found this out by querying the YUM repositories that I have on my system, looking for a package that contained a file `*/bin/kdesu`.

```
$ repoquery -qf */bin/kdesu
kde-runtime-0:4.13.3-3.fc20.x86_64
kde-runtime-0:4.11.3-2.fc20.i686
kde-runtime-0:4.13.3-3.fc20.i686
kde-runtime-0:4.11.3-2.fc20.x86_64
```